# Heroku login fails: Error: unable to get local issuer certificate when trying to deploy django app

Tags: django, heroku, heroku-cli

I want to deploy my django app to heroku. I am using company PC, windows10. Company is not IT company, it is contruction company. So IT team is not helpfull in some development cases.
When I want to login from heroku cli, I got this error:

```
D:\coding\taksi>heroku login
heroku: Press any key to open up the browser to login or q to exit:
Error: unable to get local issuer certificate
```

What have I tried already:

- Check/Set Variable SSL_CERT_DIR=YourCetrFolder (I don't have such file, company IT team has no idea about this)

I did my deployment via browser, but some tasks are not possible with web interface. for example I want to create super user after deployment, I want to migrate my database after deployment. those tasks are impossible via heroku web.(as far as i know, of course if there is a way to do those via heroku web page, please let me know. as long as it does my job, it is not important whether it is heroku cli or heroku webpage for me)

thanks in advance.

Comment: Heroku TLS 1.0 and 1.1 is disabled since yesterday. Are you sure your client supports TLS 1.2?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. how to know which tls I am at? heroku version info is like this in me: C:\Users\a.soyunjaliyev>heroku version        
heroku/7.53.0 win32-x64 node-v12.21.0

Comment: Heroku is at TLS 1.2 now. You can Google how to enable TLS 1.2 on Win7 or older.